IP MTU and Interface MTU
So im facing a problem with understanding which MTU(ip MTU or interface MTU) is the one responsible for fragmentation. I know that ip MTU is at layer3 and interface MTU is at layer 2.just an example: supposing that interface MTU is 1600 bytes, and ip MTU is 1550 bytes and a packet at layer 3 is 2000 bytes will it be fragmented according to 1600 bytes(so will it be fragmented to be no more than 1600 bytes) or will it be fragmented according to the interface MTU.

The IPv4 MTU is 65515. It is typically the data-link MTU that will force fragmentation, although fragmentation is something that is going away. Many companies now drop packet fragments to prevent fragmentation attacks, and IPv6 has eliminated in-path fragmentation by requiring PMTUD.

isnt the ip MTU same as the interface MTU or less than it ? also many say that ip MTU is linked to the fragmentation process,  i dont know how exactly is it linked if the interface MTU is what decides whether fragmentation should take place or not.

No. IPv6 packets can be up to 65535, and you subtract the 20 to 60 octet header to arrive at the MTU. IPv6 packets can have a payload (MTU) of 65535 under normal circumstances, but IPv6 has a jumbo extension option, too.

You are confusing yourself by using terms out of context. "MTU" is an IETF term and only used for the maximum IP packet size on the network layer (OSI L3), commonly for a specific interface.
Terms are often jumbled around, so "interface MTU" might be used for the maximum frame size of an interface or data link layer protocol (OSI L2). However, strictly speaking "interface MTU" is the IP MTU over a specific interface, which differs from the maximum frame size by the L2 overhead. You should not use "MTU" for anything else than the network layer.
The correct term to use for arbitrary layers is protocol data unit PDU. The maximum L3 PDU is the MTU. The maximum L2 PDU is the maximum frame size.

supposing that interface MTU is 1600 bytes, and ip MTU is 1550 bytes and a packet at layer 3 is 2000 bytes will it be fragmented according to 1600 bytes

If the maximum frame size on an interface is 1600 octets and the (IP) MTU is 1550 octets (=50 octets L2 overhead), those 1550 octets is the maximum fragment size.

a packet at layer 3 is 2000 bytes will it be fragmented according to 1600 bytes

A packet of 2000 bytes (20 bytes header + 1980 bytes payload) sent over that interface will be fragmented into 1550 + 70 octets - the second fragment also requires an IP header.

thank you so much, this makes sense now @Zac67
